# Adwords API report, what is AutomaticContent and Content?

Tags: google-ads-api

Pulling a report from the Adwords API. Trying to list out keywords ranked by impression.

Two 'keywords', AutomaticContent and Content appear in the list a few times. What are these? We are not running ads on those keywords so I assume Google is inserting them to mean something.

This is the AWQL we are using:

`SELECT+Criteria,Impressions+FROM+KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT+where+Impressions>0`

Comment: If you get the Keyword ID too, maybe it has something to do with this: 
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting#keywordid3000000

Comment: @fabrigm that looks promising! I will pull the IDs.